# PostgreSQL select query loading issue some time only?

Tags: c#, sql, node.js, postgresql

This query loads some time and take 1 minute to complete, that time we remove the 'user_action_id' it completed with in millisecond. Most of the value in the 'user_action_id' is null.

```
select sum(Round(((cast((bd.posi_loose/u.uom_max_loose) as numeric))+bd.quantity)*bd.price,2)) 
into totalAmountInItemVoid
from t_bill_details bd
left join public.c_terminal trml on trml.id=bd.terminal_id
left join public.t_bill bil on bil.id=bd.bill_id and bil.terminal_id=bd.terminal_id
left join public.c_uom u on u.id=bd.uom_id
where bil.status!=7 
  and bil.status!=9 
  and bd.user_action_id=2 
  and bil.created_by=userid 
  and bil.eod_businessday_id is null;
```

Comment: @Stefanov.sm when you make edit on code, try to make it more readable too. He hide `into ...` on right side of query.

Answer (score 0):

If most values in `user_action_id` column are null, you can improve the look-up performance by creating a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX yourIndex ON t_bill_details(user_action_id) 
WHERE user_action_id IS NOT NULL;
```

That will ignore the rows with null values when executing the query, thus saving execution time.

You can also use [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) over your query to get more insights about why adding that condition to the `WHERE` clause is causing such a performance degradation. With that information you will be able to take a more informed decision - my partial index suggestion is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Start by simplifying the query.  The `LEFT JOIN`s are being turned into inner joins anyway so express them correctly:

```
select sum(Round(((cast((bd.posi_loose/u.uom_max_loose) as numeric))+bd.quantity)*bd.price,2)) 
into totalAmountInItemVoid
from t_bill_details bd join
     public.c_terminal trml
     on trml.id = bd.terminal_id join
     public.t_bill bil
     on bil.id = bd.bill_id and
        bil.terminal_id = bd.terminal_id left join
     public.c_uom u
     on u.id = bd.uom_id
where bil.status not in (7, 9) and
      bd.user_action_id = 2 and
      bil.created_by = userid and
      bil.eod_businessday_id is null;
```

This query should be able to take advantage of an index on `t_bill_details(user_action_id)`.  I suspect that the performance issue has to do with different execution plans with this condition.  You would need to look at the execution plans to see what is happening.

I also wonder how a `filter` clause would work.  Remove the `db.user_action_id = 2` from the `where` clause and instead try:

```
select sum(Round(((cast((bd.posi_loose/u.uom_max_loose) as numeric))+bd.quantity)*bd.price,2)) filter (where db.user_action_id = 2)
```